# artisan migrate broken: undefined property

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm dealing with an broken artisan. Everytime I run any  migrate command it says:

```
  [ErrorException]
  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$projects
```

No matter if I delete the projects table and model it just can't run the migrate command again. I've created a relation between a user and a project, a user can have many projects and ever since that's been introduced my whole application seems broken. Things like `Auth::check()` give the same error.

Project Model:

```
class Projects extends Eloquent {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo("User");
    }

    public function android_app_entries() {
        return $this->hasMany("AndroidAppEntries");
    }
}
```

User model:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';

    public static $rules = array(
        'username'=>'required|between:6,18',
        'password'=>'required|between:6,18',
        'project_id'=>'required'
    );

    // Artist __has_many__ projects
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Projects');
    }
```

Project migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProjectsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('project_name');
            $table->string('client_name');
            $table->integer('users_id');
            $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });



    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('projects');
    }
```

User migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password', 64);
        $table->string('role');
        $table->string('remember_token');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

I'm hoping someone else has also experienced this and might be able to help me.

Another note: I've renamed a controller which was created by artisan. Not sure if that has any influence. Did a composer dump autoload to be sure..

Update:

Even after completely removing all the models and the complete database the error persists. I even rolled back to the code that worked this afternoon without the changes from tonight. So my guess is that the whole installation got faulty..

laravel.log:

```
[2015-01-29 21:29:03] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$projects' in /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php:56
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php(56): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/var/www/larave...', 56, Array)
#1 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php(38): Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar->compileComponents(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder))
#2 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php(34): Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar->compileSelect(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder))
#3 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1234): Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar->compileSelect(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder))
#4 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1359): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->toSql()
#5 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1349): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#6 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1336): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->getFresh(Array)
#7 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1771): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#8 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1731): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->aggregate('max', Array)
#9 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php(105): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->max('batch')
#10 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php(58): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository->getLastBatchNumber()
#11 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(158): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository->getLast()
#12 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/ResetCommand.php(61): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->rollback(false)
#13 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(112): Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\ResetCommand->fire()
#14 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(100): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(889): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(193): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\ResetCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /var/www/laravel-develop/artisan(59): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#20 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Do you have any other migrations? Or maybe seeders that you run too? The error means that somewhere you access `->projects` on an object that doesn't have that property. (You probably think it's your model and try to access the relationship)

Comment: Yes I got some other migrations but since I added the relationship it's broken. Seeders that are related to any Project kind of thing are also removed. At last, the fun thing is that if I do a search on `->project` on the whole project there are no results.. Seems like a cache problem or something

Comment: What if you remove the relationship?

Comment: No result, removed everything which has something to do with projects. Seems like it's super agressively cached. Really frustrates me. Because I might have to re create a new app or something..

Comment: Take a look at your logs (`app/storage/logs/laravel.log`) and see if you can find out from where the error is coming...

Comment: Doesn't give me more information, it basically fails at a `is_null`check on a query object

Comment: Try running `php artisan clear-compiled` if you haven't already and then search for `projects` everywhere again (and maybe update your question with the results) it has to be somewhere...

Comment: I'm assuming my User model is corrupt. Everytime I do Auth::check() or Auth::guest() it crashes. When I remove the User model it stops giving me the error but it complains about User.php missing. The weird thing is dat artisan still gives the same error when User model is removed and every bit of cache is cleared.

Comment: Looking at it your User model looks fine to me. After you removed it make sure to run `composer dump-autoload` that should make the "missing" error go away

Comment: I already did that as well.. I'm just considering a fresh installation and report this as a bug. I'm really amazed how easy my Laravel project sinks to the bottom when some renaming is done or whatever caused this to blow up.

Comment: It's really strange... Let me know if you figure the reason out.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually after rolling back not only the app code I also rolled back the vendor laravel code from a working copy which did the trick. Strange though that the vendor directory can get broken.